# how can i find one highest value of nonusboxoffice

Tags: sql

```
Select  TITLE, RELEASEYEAR, MAX(NONUSBOXOFFICE) 
From BOXOFFICEMOJO b 
Where (b.RELEASEYEAR > 2009 AND b.RELEASEYEAR <= 2015 AND MOD(RELEASEYEAR, 2) = 1)
GROUP BY TITLE, RELEASEYEAR ;
```

How can I find the highest value of `NONUSBOXOFFICE` ?

Comment: what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the one highest nonusboxoffice:

```
Select TOP 1 TITLE, RELEASEYEAR, MAX(NONUSBOXOFFICE) 
From BOXOFFICEMOJO b 
Where (b.RELEASEYEAR > 2009 AND b.RELEASEYEAR <= 2015 AND MOD(RELEASEYEAR, 2) = 1)
GROUP BY TITLE, RELEASEYEAR ;
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, but i  need to display title , releaseyear and nonusboxoffice highest value.

Comment: Not all RDMSs  use TOP clause.